# Ubuntu Xenial kernel crash on extended display

Tags: kernel, multiple-monitors, dell, 16.04

I have dell xps 15 9550, when I connect my extended display the laptop display starts to flicker like crazy when I hove the mouse over it. After few seconds ubuntu freezes. ctrl + alt + 1 or 2 does not return to console. Clicking power button does not trigger shut down. Only when long press power button computer shuts down.

I can only use external display or laptop display not 2 at the same time.

Sometimes I manage to get 2 working but it usually is a long process that involves removing ~/.config/monitors.xml (not sure it makes a difference)

Sometime I takes me 30 mins of tries to get 2 monitors working. Its not worth it in long run.

I went through dmesg and kernel logs and there is nothing about the crash.

I cannot install ubuntu 15.10 as kernel does not support my pci-e ssd drive. (http://www.dell.com/uk/business/p/xps-15-9550-laptop/pd?ref=33_productImage&oc=bnx5516&model_id=xps-15-9550-laptop)

I have also experienced couple times a complete freeze that corrupts my files that I was editing.

I am attaching my kernel log, ubuntu crashed on me today couple times so hopefully you can see something there.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2tUFAyLcWUuVkFzcF9IMHBqU00